# MVC Implementation in Yii 1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am currently looking to redesign a feature on my web application.
The web application utilizes Yii (version 1) for the back-end.

In this instance I have a model and controller. The model is used to store all the userTracking data and is appropriately a userTracking model however the actual logic for the model is in a controller called UserController. I have a function called actionTrackUser($id) which is used to implement various tracking logic for a particular user and create a model for that user.

I however now need to extrapolate this functionality from the UserController to a seperate trackingController which will implement tracking for various models.

I need to be able to utilize this functionality however in the new controller and old controller. I was wondering as to the best approach for this in Yii 1 that implements MVC correctly. I thought about making a trackingModel and having the userTracking model extend that but then I would have a lot of business logic in a model in order to use it in two places.

I am fairly new to MVC and Yii so I was wondering as to the best approach to take here?

I have purposely left code out of this question as it is more a theoretical question regarding the implementation of such functionality in Yii.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do "MVC" in PHP alone. Just forget about the term and write testable, decoupled code based on the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: Thank you however in this instance I cannot rewrite the original code as it is somewhat of a black box and developed by another developer. I can extract the controller code to a model however it still needs to be called in two places and I feel that using a model to achieve this is the incorrect approach however I cannot think of another solution here. Thanks @PeeHaa

Comment: Well as stated your question cannot be answered, because the code has nothing and will never have anything to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there may be a 'best' approach. However, you need to choose an approach that works best for you. Be guided by what will work for your situation, and what will make manageable code for you and others in the future.

There is nothing wrong with your current userTracking model and controller. You state that the "actual logic for the model is in a controller." You may want to relook at that to move appropriate data management, constraints and validation rules to the model at least.

You can move functions to a separate trackingController and still use the userTracking model. There is no rules that says you have to have a matching model and controller set, and it is quite possible for a controller to manage more that one model at a time.

I generally start with activeRecord models, which map against data stores (database tables in most cases). I use corresponding Form models to reflect forms that are markedly different from activeRecord models, and I use domain models to reflect complex business objects that are feature rich, and reflect lots of runtime attributes (like calculated fields) and state data (like publish state, which are calculated from other fields - for example a user could have validation status, paid status, active status, account level and so on that all work together to indicate what activity is possible for the user).